# Use LEFT JOIN inserting into MySQL via Form

Tags: php, mysql, join, insert

I have made a form with some text fields that are inserted manualy.

All these fields are filled in Table 1, except 1. I have made a dropmenu menu which is calling information from table 2.

```
<div>Geslacht</div>
<select name='geslacht'>
<?php 
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $line['Geslacht'];?>"> <?php echo $line['Geslacht'];?> </option>
```

So far so good, the drop down menu does select the information.

What i want to accomplish:

I want to link the field in table 1 to the field in table 2, so when i change the value in table 2, say like: change Man to Male, every Person in table 1, gets the value Man changed to Male.

Table 1 structure:
PersonID Name Gender
1        John *link to table 2*

Table 2 structure:
ID     Gender
1      Male
2      Female

I have been told to use a LEFT JOIN for this, but i'm lost, i have no clue where to start this. Can anyone give me starts/heads up?

My current INSERT code is:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persoon (voornaam, tussenvoegsel, achternaam,
        straatnaam, huisnummer, toevoeging, bsnnummer, geboortedatum, geslacht) VALUES ('".$persoon_voornaam."', '".$persoon_tussenvoegsel."', '".$persoon_achternaam."',
         '".$persoon_straatnaam."', '".$persoon_huisnummer."', '".$persoon_toevoeging."', '".$persoon_bsnnummer."', '".$persoon_geboortedatum."', '".$persoon_geslacht."')") or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the join doesn't come into play until you're `SELECT`ing data back :)

Table 1 fields:

```
id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT
name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
gender INT(11) UNSIGNED
```

Table 2 fields:

```
gender_id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT
gender_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
```

So let's say you have two entries in table 2: `1 = male` and `2 = female`.

When you insert into Table 1, you'll utilize the 1 and 2 instead of 'male' and 'female.'

```
INSERT INTO table1 (name, gender) VALUES ('Josh', 1);
```

When you go to `SELECT` the information back, you'll use the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.gender = t2.gender_id WHERE t1.name = 'Josh';
```

Then in your result set, you'll have all of your normal data PLUS whatever was linked from `table2`, i.e. `gender_name`.

Hopefully that made some sense.

Comment: Thanks! I think i was a bit confused, i just had to take the last step to understand the "LEFT JOIN". I've made it work, thanks again!!